# Trying to load a TileMap causes TypeError

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've been trying to get a tilemap loaded into Phaser that I exported as JSON from Tiled, but it keeps causing the following error when I add it:

[image: phaser error]

I've tried to copy the Phaser examples and change the strings to match my files to see if it was something I did wrong - still didn't work.

The code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phasergame', {preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });
var map;
var layer;

function preload() {

    game.load.tilemap('map', 'assets/tilemap/maze.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
    game.load.image('tiles', 'assets/tilemap/tiles.png');

}

function create() {
    map = game.add.tilemap('map');
    map.addTilesetImage('tiles',tiles);
    layer = map.createLayer('Walls');
    layer.resizeWorld();
}

function update() {}

function render() {}
};
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.6.2/phaser.js"></script>
```

My maze.json from Tiled: https://gist.github.com/spideynn/efe8e787031ffae89ddb354db129fb53

My tiles.png: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bJRB.png

Answer (score 0):

Is the name of your tileset the same as the one you used to create the tilemap in Tiled? If in Tiled the tileset had the name `tiles.png` then you have to make sure that the tileset that you are loading in phaser also has the same name.

Comment: The tileset in Tiled and the image have the same name

Comment: @Spideynn are you sure you have the same name? In your [JSON] (https://gist.github.com/spideynn/efe8e787031ffae89ddb354db129fb53#file-maze-json-L44) file, it says that the name of the tileset is * tiles.png * whereas the tileset you are loading has the name * tilemap.png*

Comment: I updated the code that I'm using in the original post - I'm pretty sure that I'm using the same names now

Comment: Try using this:

Comment: Try using this:
map.addTilesetImage('tiles', 'tiles');
In place of:
map.addTilesetImage('tiles');

Comment: I tried your example for myself and it works fine for me. This is my index.html file.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a8b95e432f10cb295cdfd5ebfc4f8e0f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130301/discussion-between-b-naeem-and-spideynn).